# StreamTokenizer behavior

Tags: java

I'm in the midst of developing my own parser for a lab and I've run into some strange behavior with StreamTokenizer. It seems that anything surrounded by single quotes is getting skipped over.

Code

```
StreamTokenizer st = new StreamTokenizer(new FileReader("input.txt"));
boolean eof = false;

do{
   int i = 0;
   int token = st.nextToken();
   switch (token){
       case StreamTokenizer.TT_EOF:
            System.out.println("EOF");
            eof = true;
            break;
       case StreamTokenizer.TT_EOL:
            System.out.println("EOL");
            break;
       case StreamTokenizer.TT_WORD:
            System.out.println("Word: " + st.sval);
            break;
       case StreamTokenizer.TT_NUMBER:
            System.out.println("Number: " + st.nval);
            break;
       default:
            System.out.println((char) token + " encountered.");
            break;

   }
} while (!eof);
```

Input:

```
top 'AT THE TOP' {
   l 2{ window{Open Up} } 
}
```

Output:

```
Word: top
' encountered.
{ encountered.
Word: l
Number: 2.0
{ encountered.
Word: window
{ encountered.
Word: Open
Word: Up
} encountered.
} encountered.
} encountered.
EOF
```

I noticed that I can set the quote char by using the following method:

```
st.quoteChar('\'');
```

I thought that this would allow me to set the quote char that, if encountered, the next token will be everything up until the next quote char.

Unfortunately that did not work as I thought, and now I am stuck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/StreamTokenizer.html#ttype) says

> ```
> public int ttype
> ```
>
> For a quoted string token, its value is the quote character.

and the [`sval`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/StreamTokenizer.html#sval) docs say

> When the current token is a quoted string token, this field contains the body of the string.

so you need to have a

```
case '\'':
  System.out.println("Quoted value is " + st.sval);
  break;
```

or something similar to handle single quoted strings or reset the syntax so it's not treating `'` as a `quoteChar`.

Comment: @FatalProphet, Great to hear.  Happy parsing!